# Downloading PDF with AngularJS and WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I have an AngularJS app that I need to call our WebAPI to download a PDF file. The PDF is successfuly downloaded, but when it's opened, it's blank.
I used Postman to test my webapi code and that gives me the correct PDF when I open that. Another think to note, the PDF to download is about 45kb and the empty PDF that is downloaded is about 77kb.
Here is my API code:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetStatement(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var path = "c:/temp/";
        var filename = "pdffile.pdf";
        var filePath = path + filename;

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            // PDF file exists
            var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            IHttpActionResult response;
            HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            responseMsg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(dataBytes);
            responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filename;
            responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            response = ResponseMessage(responseMsg);

            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            // File not found
            }

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

And here is my AngularJS code (I've tried an arraybuffer as the responseType which still gives me and empty PDF)

```
 $http.post('https://localhost/api/download-statement/1', { responseType: 'blob' })
    .then(function (response) {
        var binaryData = [];
        binaryData.push(response.data);

        var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: "application/pdf" }));
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = file;
        a.download =  "file.pdf";
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        // remove `a` following `Save As` dialog, 
        // `window` regains `focus`
        window.onfocus = function () {
              document.body.removeChild(a)
        }
    },
    function (error) {

});
```

WHat am I doing wrong? I've tried many different examples, but they all result in an empty PDF.

Comment: If you're running out of options, you could consider using something like [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) to rule out `createObjectURL` doing something funky in translating the server blob data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should do the trick,

```
  $http({
        url: 'https://localhost/api/download-statement/1',
        method: "POST",
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"});
        var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(objectUrl);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });
```